# One word for 'Completeness and Correctness'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one word for the phrase 'Completeness and Correctness' as in submitted documents.

As an example say I have to give status of a payment that require examination of some documents with respect to some agreed submissions and values set as standard. The invoices were submitted around 5 months ago, and the statement should allude to reason for the long time taken for vetting. For this the statement should go like this:"*The invoices were submitted on 24.08.2015, and were being examined thoroughly for its completeness and correctness*"

This is a part of a long reply. So I am looking forward to be as much concise as possible. Hence the quest for one for 'Completeness and Correctness'

Comment: Why do you need just one word? What is wrong with using the two words?

Comment: Just to keep the communication concise

Comment: Subsume completeness into correctness and just use "correctness."

Comment: @ Rathony. I have edited the question throwing in some background

Answer (score 3):

The terms *complete* and *correct* are not qualities of the document on its own; they are references to the state of the document in relation to a set of rules.

If you don't mind a shift from qualities of the document itself to its compliance with your rules, you can use the word *validity*, as in *checked for validity* (or for *compliance*, for that matter).

The document would not be *valid* if the entries completed were incorrect, and it would also not be *valid* if entries were incomplete. Both are required for the document to be considered *valid*.

> **Validity**
>   1.1 The state of being legally or officially binding or acceptable
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/validity)

Comment: Upvoted this answer. Deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

More context would help here. I don't believe that we have a single word that covers those two independent concepts. It may be better usage not to use either word: In general, a reviewer would not only review for completeness and correctness, they might also consider criteria such as intelligibility, style, brevity and pertinence.

It might be sufficient to simply say:

```
The document has been reviewed by ...
```

without specifying all the criteria; it is surely obvious that a review of a document would consider whether it is correct so do we add value by spelling that out? Do we need to spell out all the criteria?

Comment: Do you believe there is a single word? Isn't there a larger question of usage here: how do we convey our intended meaning?

Comment: I think my point is more helpful. Arguably I'm trying to be complete as well as correct ;-)